# get current date with 'yyyy-MM-dd' format in Angular 4

Tags: angular

How i can get the current date with a specific format 'yyyy-MM-dd', for today by example i with that the result be: '2018-07-12', with using just the command

```
myDate = new Date();
```

thanks a lot

Comment: you can use angular date pipe check this https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: I need the value in my type scrript file

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use DatePipe for formatting Date in Angular.

In ts if you want to format date then you can inject DatePipe as Service in constructor like this

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './name.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./name.component.scss'],
    providers: [DatePipe]
})

myDate = new Date();
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){
    this.myDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

And if you want to format in html file, 'Shortdate' will return date of type MM/DD/YY

```
{{myDate | date: 'shortDate' }}
```

As of Angular 6, this also works,

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';

formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en');
```

Comment: i imported DatePipe from @angular/common and i applied your code, but i have an error message that format not existing on DateType type?

Comment: You also need to add DatePipe in providers

Comment: i did that, the error messag is: ERROR in src/app/filter-test/filter-test.component.ts(40,33): error TS2339: Property 'format' does not exist on type 'DatePipe'.

Comment: the only method proposed with this.datePipe is transform?

Comment: I solved the problem with this commands: test: string; myDate = new Date(); this.test = this.datePipe.transform(this.myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); it works

Comment: this returns a string. what if i need a Date type?

Answer (score 33):

you can try doing this.

---

**component.ts**

```
currentDate = new Date();
```

---

**component.html**

```
{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Comment: simple, easy and clean

Answer (score 10):

You can use `date:'yyyy-MM-dd'` pipe

```
curDate=new Date();

<p>{{curDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</p>
```

Comment: I need tha value in my type script file

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to display then you can use date pipe in HTML like this :

**Just Date**:

```
your date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'
```

**Date With Time**:

```
your date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a'
```

And if you want to take input only date from new Date() then :

You can use angular formatDate() in ts file like this -

```
currentDate = new Date();

const cValue = formatDate(currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US');
```

Comment: formatDate() returns a string. A return of Date type is needed. whats the solution now?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example:

```
function MethodName($scope)
{
    $scope.date = new Date();
}
```

You can change the format in view here we have a code

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MethodName">
    My current date is {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} . 
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am in Angular 4 and i want this value in my type script file, not in html

Answer (score 2):

**In Controller ,**

```
 var DateObj = new Date();

 $scope.YourParam = DateObj.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (DateObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + DateObj.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 2):

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
     <h5 style="color:#ffffff;">{{myDate | date:'fullDate'}}</h5>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
myDate = Date.now();    //date
```

Comment: An answer is much more likely to be useful to people in the future (and get upvotes) if code is accompanied by a short, clear explanation of why your answer solves the problem and, in the case of an old question with 8 other answers, an explanation as to why your answer adds something that was missing from the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

**In HTML FILE**

```
{{date_variable|date:'fullDate'}}
```

Explanation

Using pipes is better because in pipes we can transform output without changing the input rather than using other methods. Here, I used the following link as `fullDate` you can use your own combination

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   import * as moment from 'moment';

     ngOnInit() {
     this.date = moment().format("YYYY Do MMM");
                }
```

Comment: this returns a `string` type, not `Date` type

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

Then as per your requirement just change locale for your application:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr);

//Provide the locale in any Module or Component by the LOCALE_ID token.
providers: [
 {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To format date in Angular we can use Angular Datepipe.

For an example we can use following code to get formatted date in our code.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-name-class',
    templateUrl: './name.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./name.component.scss']
})

export class NameComponent implements OnInit {
  
  // define datepipe

  datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
  
  constructor(){}

  // method to get formatted date

  getformattedDate(){
    
    var date = new Date();
    var transformDate = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    return transformDate;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this is to use together w/ `<input type="datetime-local">` such as

`<input matInput #dateTimeInput type="datetime-local" [value]="todayAsString" step="1" [min]="todayAsString">`

then `todayAsString` should be set as

```
this.todayAsString = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en');
this.todayAsString += 'T' + formatDate(new Date(), 'hh:mm', 'en');
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: how about not return a string, but rather a Date type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple
var dt = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

Comment: yes, it's right but I prefer DatePipe.

Answer (score 0):

**TS File =>**

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  //Add This
  myDate = Date.now();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**HTML File =>**

```
    //Formatted Date.
    <p>{{myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</p>
    //Default date format
    <p>{{myDate | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TS(TypeScript)**

```
public currentDate = new Date();
```

**HTML**

```
{{ currentDate | date:'yyyy年MM月dd日' }}
```

**Output:**

```
2022年12月27日
```

Answer (score -1):

can use format attribute in HTML.

Comment: As an answer, this really needs more detail to actually answer the question. What `format` attribute are you referring to? Can you provide a link to documentation? A code example that demonstrates how to apply it here? Why might this approach be preferred than the accepted answer on this thread?