# Angular7 + Clarity Datepicker customisation

Tags: datepicker, angular7, vmware-clarity

I'm working on an Angular 7 application with [Project Clarity v1.0](https://v1.clarity.design) as a design system.

I did many forms but facing some issue regarding [Datepicker](https://v1.clarity.design/datepicker) custom format.

I went through the documentation but there is no example or text about how to use custom date format, dis-allowed past/previous dates...etc something like [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker). They are mention each and everything about how much you can play around with date picker element.

**Project Clarity Example**

```
<form clrForm clrLayout="vertical">
  <input type="date" [(clrDate)]="date" newFormLayout="true">
</form>
```

I tried, angular way to setup custom date format as described into [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300093/9567890), but nothing like works. Can anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The Clarity Date Picker may not have all of the features of another date picker, and there are some enhancements in our backlog currently. If there is a specific issue that is missing, please search https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues for existing issues or you may create a new one.

Also in this case, you shouldn't need to use `newFormLayout="true"` on the control since you are already using the `clrForm` directive on your form.

Custom date format: We use the locale from Angular to determine the format. This is not currently overridable beyond that.

Disallow date ranges: This is not currently supported, but issue is https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/3009.