# How to set the id for element that matches a given value?

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I have in Angular 7 the following:

```
<th *ngFor="let day of weekDays"><div>{{day}}</div></th>
```

but want to set the `<th id="today"` for the single element among all `weekDays` that corresponds/equals to `today`.

Given that:

```
  this.today = "Fri 5/7";
```

The result should be:

```
<th id="today"><div>Fri 5/7</div></th>
<th><div>Sat 6/7</div></th>
<th><div>Sun 7/7</div></th>
<th><div>Mon 8/7</div></th>
<th><div>Tue 9/7</div></th>
<th><div>Wed 10/7</div></th>
<th><div>Thu 11/7</div></th>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: *How to set the class for element that matches a given value?* and you are using `id="today"`!

Comment: Do you want to set Class with Condition?

Comment: Could you update with what is the result you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 <th *ngFor="let day of weekDays" [attr.id]="today==day?'today':null"><div>{{day}}</div></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call a function which set id depending on date:

```
<th *ngFor="let day of weekDays" [attr.id]="returnStringBasedOnCondition()"><div>{{day}}</div></th>
```

and you can use following links to get `today` :

[How to check if input date is equal to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215556/how-to-check-if-input-date-is-equal-to-todays-date/26257591)

[get current date with 'yyyy-MM-dd' format in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299944/get-current-date-with-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditionally attribute like that. If `null` it will remove your attribute:

```
<th *ngFor="let day of weekDays" 
    [attr.id]="value === day ? 'today' : null">
    <div>{{day}}</div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
<th *ngFor="let day of weekDays" [id.today]="isToday()"><div>{{day}}</div></th>
```

And of course add the function `isToday()` in your typescript.
I usually use conditional classes and never tried with conditional IDs but this should work.